# При извлечении подстроки средствами PHP появляются символы вопросов

Tags: php, строки

Здравствуйте!
Возникает проблема, при обращении к элементам строки на русском языке.
При обращении к элементу 0 строки в переменной `$phrase`, выводится вопрос �
Обойти это у меня получилось только путем использования `mb_substr($phrase,$i,1,'UTF-8')`. Но этот вариант мне не подходит, так как каждый символ строки должен отправляться в функцию где он ищется в качестве ключа массива и возвращает значение.

```
function getImageSymbol($symbol)
{
    $symbol = mb_strtolower($symbol,'UTF-8');
    $data = array(
        '0' => 'alphabet-0.png',
        '1' => 'alphabet-1.png',
        '2' => 'alphabet-2.png',
        '3' => 'alphabet-3.png',
        '4' => 'alphabet-4.png',
        '5' => 'alphabet-5.png',
        '6' => 'alphabet-6.png',
        '7' => 'alphabet-7.png',
        '8' => 'alphabet-8.png',
        '9' => 'alphabet-9.png',
        'а' => 'alphabet-A.png',
        'б' => 'alphabet-B.png',
        'ь' => 'alphabet-bb.png',
        'ъ' => 'alphabet-bbb.png',
        'ц' => 'alphabet-C.png',
        'ч' => 'alphabet-ch.png',
        'д' => 'alphabet-D.png',
        '-' => 'alphabet-dash.png',
        '.' => 'alphabet-dot1.png',
        ':' => 'alphabet-dot2.png',
        ';' => 'alphabet-dot3.png',
        '?' => 'alphabet-dot4.png',
        '!' => 'alphabet-dot5.png',
        ',' => 'alphabet-dot6.png',
        'е' => 'alphabet-E.png',
        'ё' => 'alphabet-EE.png',
        'э' => 'alphabet-EEE.png',
        'ф' => 'alphabet-F.png',
        'г' => 'alphabet-G.png',
        'х' => 'alphabet-H.png',
        'и' => 'alphabet-i.png',
        'й' => 'alphabet-ii.png',
        'к' => 'alphabet-K.png',
        'л' => 'alphabet-L.png',
        'м' => 'alphabet-M.png',
        'н' => 'alphabet-N.png',
        '--' => 'alphabet-Ndash.png',
        'о' => 'alphabet-O.png',
        'п' => 'alphabet-P.png',
        'р' => 'alphabet-R.png',
        'с' => 'alphabet-S.png',
        'ш' => 'alphabet-SH.png',
        'щ' => 'alphabet-SHCH.png',
        'т' => 'alphabet-T.png',
        'у' => 'alphabet-U.png',
        'в' => 'alphabet-V.png',
        'ы' => 'alphabet-Y.png',
        'я' => 'alphabet-YA.png',
        'ю' => 'alphabet-yy.png',
        'з' => 'alphabet-Z.png',
        'ж' => 'alphabet-zh.png',
    );
    return !empty( $data[$symbol] ) ?  $data[$symbol] : 'alphabet-' . $symbol;
}

function makePhrase($phrase)
{
    foreach (explode(' ', $phrase) as $word):
            for($i = 0; $i < strlen($word); $i++):
                $symbol = mb_substr($word,$i,1,'UTF-8'); ?>
                <img src="assets/images/alphabet-min/<?= getImageSymbol( $symbol ) ?>.png" alt="">
            <?php endfor;
    endforeach;
}
```

Comment: используйте mb_strlen($word) в счетчике цикла и все будет правдоподобно работать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой знак вопроса - это половина двухбайтного символа UTF-8. Дело в том, что каждый символ русского текста в UTF-8 занимает 2 байта, а функция `substr()` по умолчанию считает все символы однобайтными и может разрезать русский символ по-середине.

Вам придется для UTF-8 либо использовать mb-функции `mb_substr()`, `mb_strlen()`, либо включить на уровне php.ini замену классических строковых функций mb-вариантами, установив в секции [mbstring] значение директивы `mbstring.func_overload` равным 2

```
[mbstring]
...
mbstring.func_overload = 2
```

После этого вы сможете использовать с русским текстом в UTF-8 классические функции `substr()` и `strlen()`. Однако изменение `mbstring.func_overload` возможно не на всех хостингах, кроме того, он может "ломать" работу других приложений, например, того же phpMyAdmin.

Comment: он уже использует mb_substr()

Comment: @splash58 Угу, нужно либо mb_substr() и mb_strlen(), либо переключаться в mbstring.func_overload = 2 и использоваться substr() и strlen(). Поправил ответ.